creating folds for cross validation based on data labels in pandas
I have a dataset from a scientific lab study, with columns specyfying an unique number for each person which attended and a time point specyfying which time was each person attending the experiment (a maximum of 4 times), a label column which i use for model training and many columns with stats obtained during the study.
After training a model, I want to perform a k-fold cross validation but ensure that data from one experiment (so each unique combination of a participant number and a time point) is contained in the same fold.
I wanted to use StratifiedGroupKFold from the sklearn library but I'm not sure how does it decide how to split data into groups, I'd prefer to be able to specify how to group data myself.
